# Configuration Transformation - Automatically transform local configuration

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, configuration, msbuild

I am looking for a hopefully ready, out of the box solution for my problem here. Here is outline:

- I would like to have a file named local.config that contains certain information about my local environment.
- That file will be ignored and will never make its way to the build server (ignored from gitHub).
- Whenever I build locally, transformation happen.
- Whenever I build on the server, whatever information found in main app.config is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing and there is probably better ways to do what I was after but unfortunately (and the fault is on me for not formulating the question correctly).

Modify the cproj file with the following:

```
  <UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml"    AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
```

Place your config files and transforms into your project accordingly. Every time you build, the configuration is transformed just fine.

I did not like that fact I had to have an extra base.config file but apparently, transforming from source directly to the target makes the msbuild rather upset.

Answer (score 0):

Both [SlowCheeta](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) and [Configuration Transform](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/579d3a78-3bdd-497c-bc21-aa6e6abbc859) should work for your needs.